# Certification authority limited to a domain

Tags: ssl, certificate-authority

we generate test environments on demand. We're using Let's Encrypt to provide SSL certificates. Each of the test environments needs around a dozen domain names in the form `<part>.<environment_name>.mydomain.com`.

The issue is, we sometimes hit rate limits of LE, the verification slows down the environment setup and we depend on LE to be available.

I couldn't find a way to get a wildcard certificate for two levels of subdomains so I'm thinking of creating an internal certificate authority and distribute it to our users. Ideally, I would like to limit the trust of my new CA just to `mydomain.com` in order to limit the potential damage to the users should the CA keys be misused or leak.

Is it somehow possible to limit a trusted CA to a specific domain? Thank you.

Comment: If it's a test environment, couldn't you use your own CA?

Comment: What problems did you have creating the wildcard certs? Sibling wildcards like `*.example.com` and `*.example2.com` should work just fine in the same request. Child wildcards like `*.example.com` and `*.sub.example.com` should also work. The only thing you can't do is have names that would overlap with one of the wildcards, so `*.example.com` and `site.example.com` in the same cert will be rejected because `site.example.com` is covered by `*.example.com`.

Comment: @TorinCarey this is exactly what I'd like to do, sorry it wasn't clear from the question. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to limit the effect of this CA to just one domain.

Comment: @RyanBolger this is problematic due to the structure of the domain names. The `<environment_name>` is the dynamic part (chosen by the developer who wants to spin up the environment), but for this environment, I need around 12 subdomains. It is not easy to change the application to support different structure of domain names.

Comment: Maybe, depends on environment. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31376/can-i-restrict-a-certification-authority-to-signing-certain-domains-only

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Sadly, it seems the support isn't there yet (we have a lot of OSX and Linux too). Something to watch for, definitely.